# Is there an ubuntu package for pygobject demos?

Tags: pygi

I know that there is a package for Pygtk demos (sudo apt-get install gtk2.0-examples) but I can't found an equivalent one for PyGObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no packages providing the `pygobject` examples, you can check the individual binaries file listing [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/precise/pygobject), all built from the `pygobject` source package.

However they are available in the git repo:

https://git.gnome.org/browse/pygobject/tree/examples

Answer (score 1):

There are examples for many of the GTK controls at: http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

I find Geany to be a handy IDE for this since you can just paste in and click run.